# Returning an array element value in php lower than php 5.4

Tags: php, arrays

I've a function which returns an array. To return the value of that array I do something like this:

```
$obj->methodname()[keyvalue];
```

This works in php 5.4 only. I want to make this code work in lower php versions.

My code:

```
class ObjectTest {
    public $ar;


    function __construct() {
       $this->ar = array(
       1 => 'beeldscherm',
       2 => 'geluidsbox',
       3 => 'toetsenbord',);
   }

   public function arr(){
    return $this->ar;
   }
}

$obj = new ObjectTest();
//by calling the method and putting square brackets and the key of the element
var_dump($obj->arr()[2]);
```

I've rewritten the code for lower versions like this:

```
public function arr($arg = null){
    if(is_null($arg)){
        return $this->ar;
    }
    return $this->ar[$arg];
   }
```

I'm doubting if this solution is an elegant one. What would you say? Any better solutions?

Comment: What's wrong with creating another method, `getArrItem()`? In fact, I'd prefer using that one almost exclusively.

Comment: I didn't say that it is wrong. Just asking if there is a better solution.

Comment: you can try if you need **Returning a reference from a function** [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like, store array in a variable and than access particular array index.

```
$arrList = var_dump($obj->arr());
echo $arrList[2];
```